# Are there naming recommendations for spring boot starters with more complex names?

Tags: spring-boot, naming-conventions, spring-boot-starter

The [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-custom-starter-naming) says how to name a Spring Boot starter for something with a simple name such as `acme`: `acme-spring-boot-starter`

However, the autoconfigured "thing" has not always such a simple name. How about a name with multiple parts?

For example CXF "splits" these parts around the base name to express a project-component hierarchy:

- **cxf**-spring-boot-starter-**jaxws**
- **cxf**-spring-boot-starter-**jaxrs**

I found other variants with these naming patterns

- **foo-bar**-spring-boot-starter
- spring-boot-starter-**foo-bar** (probably not ok because of possible conflict with starter of Spring Boot project)

Is there a naming convention or recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-custom-starter

Suffix should be `-spring-boot-starter` so in your case I'd say:

- **cxf**-**jaxws**-spring-boot-starter
- **cxf**-**jaxrs**-spring-boot-starter

Comment: Sadly Spring itself does not seem to follow it's conventions, e.g. spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon. For some reason they seem to have switched to spring-cloud-starter-xyz. for spring cloud